# Cron job wont run authenticate call

Tags: php, curl, cron

I need this code to run every 3 hours to make an API authenticate call to get a temporary token to use for making other API calls. I store it on a separate php file and update it when needed

It works in the browser but not in a cron job. All my other cron jobs work and are formatted the same. What am I missing?

*EDIT: here is my cron call -

/usr/local/bin/php /home/mysite.com/getToken.php

```
<?php

    Token();

    function Token(){
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

        $params = array("Username" => "fuu", "Password" => "bar", "PrivateKey" => "123456789");
        $auth_url = 'https://example.com/api/Rest/authenticate';
        $ch = curl_init();
        $postData = http_build_query($params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$postData");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$auth_url");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $token = $data;
        curl_close($ch);
        file_put_contents({$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} . "/Token.php", $token);
        echo $token;
    }   
?>
```

Comment: It's worth outlining your cronjob commands in this post, so that all can see what you're requesting and any possible permission issues that might influence your expected output.

Comment: Ergo, this 'might' be due to file permissions or some other cron issue, but we can't see what's going on beyond executing the php script which obv works in-browser.

Comment: Thanks, just added it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - this one is empty when executing a PHP script via shell.

Things that are set and also containing the path:

```
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(30) "/var/www/html/documentRoot.php"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(30) "/var/www/html/documentRoot.php"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(30) "/var/www/html/documentRoot.php"
  ["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
  string(30) "/var/www/html/documentRoot.php"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(0) ""
```

However, If I were you I'd rather put this into a database and read and write it from/into there. But that's just a hint.

Comment: Thank you, yes that would be more secure I'm sure